# About This Mac>Storage showing movies

Tags: macos

I'm using OSX 10.10 and its showing movies 4.03 GB in **About This Mac>Storage.** I don't have any movies in my mac. I tried to check all my files one by one but i can't find it. How to clear this occupied storage. Any idea ?